# Ignore specific levels when performing lapply in R

Tags: r, replace, levels

I have a data frame (500 obs of 40000 variables) in R where all columns consist of one or two letters interspersed with '1' and '3'. E.g., `mydata[45:50,20:25]`

```
45             C             A             3             T             C             C
46             C             G             T             C             C             A
47             C             A             G             T             C             C
48             1             A             T             3             C             3
49             C             A             G             T             C             C
50             T             A             T             C             C             A
```

I wish to replace the letters only not the numbers. My goal is for the letters to be replaced with '0' or '2' depending on their frequency. The most frequent letter therefore becoming '0' and the least frequent becoming '2'. If there is only one letter, that would become '0'.

I can achieve this without ignoring the interspersed '1' and '3' using:

`data.frame(lapply(mydata[45:50,20:25], function(x){as.numeric(factor(x, levels = names(sort(-table(x)))))}))`

which yields:

```
1             1             1             3             1             1             1
2             1             2             1             2             1             2
3             1             1             2             1             1             1
4             2             1             1             3             1             3
5             1             1             2             1             1             1
6             3             1             1             2             1             2
```

However, I would like to be able to do that while ignoring '1' and '3' in the original data frame.

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would work with a `matrix` here.

Using `grep` we make a `table` of frequencies which we `rank` on their negative values and subtract one to get zero. Since I'm not sure what you want in case of ties I chose `"first"` to get an integer (see `?rank` for options).

Then we `match` the letters on the frequencies. Finally we convert back to data frame using `type.convert` to get numeric formats.

```
m <- as.matrix(d)

ftb <- table(grep("[\\p{Lu}]", m, perl=TRUE, value=TRUE))
ftb <- rank(-ftb, ties.method="first") - 1

m.res <- apply(m, 1:2, function(x) ifelse(x %in% names(ftb), ftb[match(x, names(ftb))], x))
d.res <- type.convert(as.data.frame(m.res))
d.res
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
# 1 45  0  1  3  2  0  0
# 2 46  0  3  2  0  0  1
# 3 47  0  1  3  2  0  0
# 4 48  1  1  2  3  0  3
# 5 49  0  1  3  2  0  0
# 6 50  2  1  2  0  0  1
```

#### Edit

Since you want to look into the column frequencies, we may use the approach in an `lapply` (without matrix conversion). We can multiply the rank then by a factor 2.

```
f <- 2
d[-1] <- lapply(d[-1], function(x) {
  ftb <- (rank(-table(grep("[\\p{Lu}]", x, perl=TRUE, value=TRUE)),
              ties.method="first") - 1)*f
  stopifnot(length(ftb) <= 2)
  x <- ifelse(x %in% names(ftb), ftb[match(x, names(ftb))], x)
  as.numeric(x)
})
d
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
# 1 45  0  0  3  0  0  0
# 2 46  0  2  0  2  0  2
# 3 47  0  0  2  0  0  0
# 4 48  1  0  0  3  0  3
# 5 49  0  0  2  0  0  0
# 6 50  2  0  0  2  0  2
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(V1 = 45:50, V2 = c("C", "C", "C", "1", "C", "T"
), V3 = c("A", "G", "A", "A", "A", "A"), V4 = c("3", "T", "G", 
"T", "G", "T"), V5 = c("T", "C", "T", "3", "T", "C"), V6 = c("C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), V7 = c("C", "A", "C", "3", "C", "A"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I was probably not totally clear in my question. Your solution presently replaces the letters with 0 and 2 based on the frequency within the entire matrix. I would like them replaced with 0 and 2 based on the frequency with which the letters occur on a column by column basis.

Comment: @C24 Just put the thing in an `lapply`, see edit.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It now focuses on the columns. However, I would like the most frequent letter recoded as ''0" and least frequent as "2". Presently, your solution appears to be changing the most frequent to "0", but the least frequent to "1". 

For example: the numbers (from top to bottom) in V7 should be: "0","2","0","3","0","2" and in V2 they should be: "0","0","0","1","0","2" 

I include a link to the full dataset I would like to achieve this with in case that is helpful: https://www.filedropper.com/filemanager/public.php?service=files&t=027f117e398ebdaec6c0818ca5931d72

Comment: @C24 Have you read ties section in `?rank`?

Comment: I read it and I can't understand how any of the ties methods can give me my solution. Indeed, I tried them all and none seemed to work. I'd appreciate it if you could elaborate? 

I think I have workaround involving replacing values before and after your solution, but I would prefer a more elegant method.

Comment: @C24 Ok, just multiply the rank by 2. Your columns have just two different letters, therefore that should work. `stopifnot` added for more safety. See edit, please. What do you think?

Comment: I think it is great. Thanks very much for the great solution! It does exactly what I needed.

Comment: You're welcome @C24 , happy to hear that.